# How to set ref on three different div elements and then access array of these elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have three div elements that I want to access. I set the same 'ref' value on all three divs, but when trying to retrieve these elements in Vue, the 'elements' variable is empty. WHAT I am expecting here is an array of three div elements with the same ref value.

What's the issue in my syntax? Or am I trying to get these elements in wrong way?

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div ref="newsletterElement">
      Element1
    </div>
    <div ref="newsletterElement">
      Element2
    </div>
    <div ref="newsletterElement">
      Element2
    </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Test',
    mounted() {
      const elements = this.$refs.newsletterElement;
      console.log(elements);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Either use v-for that makes a ref an array, or treat these refs separately

Comment: Did you check the refs on vue devtools?

Comment: @EstusFlask in the end I did decide to put items into an array and then loop through them with v-for to get the div elements into a ref variable. Thanks